# Install Brackets

Tags: release-loki

I tried to install the editor Brackets using the originial .deb from the website, but dpkg and apt failed to do so.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i Brackets.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package brackets.
(Reading database ... 264099 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Brackets.deb ...
Unpacking brackets (1.7.0-16898) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brackets:
 brackets depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Package libgcrypt11 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package brackets (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brackets

$ sudo apt-get install brackets 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
brackets is already the newest version (1.7.0-16898).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 brackets : Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I install brackets? I've already installed libgcrypt11-dev and libgcrypt20

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgcrypt20 libgcrypt11-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcrypt11-dev is already the newest version (1.5.4-3+really1.6.5-2).
libgcrypt20 is already the newest version (1.6.5-2).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue as you can see [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12380) and [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10255).
The proposed solution is to install [this version of libgcrypt11](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/201289896/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb).

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo apt-get -f install`

and then re-run the deb installation using dpkg.

From `man apt-get`

```
-f, --fix-broken
        Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in
        place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any
        packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages 
        are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The 
        option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first 
        time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to 
        exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency 
        structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention 
        (which usually means using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the 
        offending packages). Use of this option together with -m may 
        produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item: 
        APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

In simple words this will install all the dependencies that is preventing you from installing your deb.

Comment: You should explain what this does for the sake of the OP.

Comment: Thank you, but if it had been so simple I wouldn't have to ask this question here ;) Installation fails with `sudo dpkg -i Brackets.Release.1.7.64-bit.deb` and `sudo apt install Brackets.Release.1.7.64-bit.deb` and `sudo apt-get install brackets`. To be sure, I ran sudo apt-get -f install between every try. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kurztipp Use this [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb)
And install the deb package and see if it works.
The package dependency (libgcrypt11) you require is now obsolete for Newer Ubuntu Versions. Try the above link.

Comment: I tried and it worked. Ran the sudo -apt-get -f install
and then tried the brackets latest version. that fixed the issue